# MySQL 5.5.9 Wont Start

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed mysql version 5.5.9 on my mac and I tried to start it using this command :

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

mysql didn't start with this command. I checked the localhost.err file in data directory and it was like this :

```
110227 22:51:14 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
110227 22:51:14 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
110227 22:51:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
110227 22:51:14 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
110227 22:51:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
110227 22:51:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
110227 22:51:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
110227 22:51:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
110227 22:51:14 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110227 22:51:14  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
110227 22:51:14  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
110227 22:51:15 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
110227 22:51:15  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
110227 22:51:15  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
110227 22:51:16 InnoDB: 1.1.5 started; log sequence number 1595916
110227 22:51:16 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
110227 22:51:16 [ERROR] Aborting

110227 22:51:16  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110227 22:51:16  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595916
110227 22:51:16 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

110227 22:51:16 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.pid ended
```

I deleted the two ib_log files, I changed my.cnf file and I got nothing.

Comment: Using MAMP or the Installs from Entropy may cause the Terminal commands that you find online to be inaccurate, as those solutions don't install over Apple shipped Apache/PHP, etc. Have you tried using `<command>+<shift>+g` from Finder, and verified that the files you're calling are actually there?

Comment: If you can find the Unix Executable in Finder, you can open Terminal and then double-click the executable from the Finder. This would at least show you which file is actually going to work, and its correct path.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have had the same problem.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135367/mysql-5-5-9-wont-start will fix it

Answer (score 2):

`--skip-locking` was removed in MySQL 5.5. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-nutshell.html).

Edit your `my.cnf` file and change "skip-locking" to "skip-external-locking".

Comment: Thanx for your answer but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: There might be other directories containing the my.cnf file which the installer will read. Check out this link: (it's not for Mac but it's the same issue) [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=894337)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue on mac, I have other MySQL instances installed from MAMP and XAMP.

Do a locate in terminal:  `locate my.cnf`

Take note of any other my.cnf files not located in your AMPPS directory.

I found that when i removed `/private/etc/my.cnf`, MySQL started with no issues.

`sudo mv /private/etc/my.cnf /private/etc/my-old.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

1 ) in the terminal , launch command : mysql_upgrade ( to create the tables that are non existent )

2 ) edit /etc/my.cnf , comment out the --skip-locking statement

that's all , happy SQLing

Comment: thanx, I typed the command ./mysql_upgrade in the bin directory and I got this :
Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed